# How to formate a cell as fraction in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, formatting, numbers, cell

I would like to type a fraction, for example 3/4, and the cell shows exactly that: 3/4.
I know that I could add a simple ' before, and would work, but I am pasting a lot of data and would like they to be interpreted all in the right way.

If I type 3/4, the cells shows times, dates depending on the format. I wanna know the code formating to show just 3/4.

Comment: Change the format of your range to Text?

Comment: I tried, but did not work. Typing 3/4 and formatting as text, the cell shows 43924

Comment: Change the format of your range to Text *before typing*, sorry.

Comment: format the cell `# ?/4` before typing.